# For which values of $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$, is this $4\times 4$ matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

For which values  of $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$, is the matrix $A$ diagonalizable?

Here,

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a & 2 & d & e \\
b & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
c & 0 & f & 0
\end{array}
\right).$$

I found the eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_{1}=3,\lambda_{2}=f\,\textrm{(if $f\neq 0$)},\lambda_3=0,\lambda_{4}=e .$$

Do I really need to compute the eigenvectors to find (or not) some conditions about $a,b,c,d,e$? Or there is another way to approache this problem
?

Comment: You can use row and column operations to diagonalize the matrix to $Diag(3,2,1,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should obtain eigenvalues of 0,1,2,3. These are distinct and so the matrix is diagonalizable.